# Need help in understanding a proof from Hatcher's Algebraic Topology (proposition $0.19$)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

**Proposition:** Suppose $(X,A)$ and $(Y,A)$ satisfy the homotopy extension property(HEP) and $f:X \to Y$ is a homotopy equivalence with $f\vert_A=1$ then $f$ is a homotopy equivalance relative $A$.

**Proof:**

**Step1:** Construct a homotopy from $g$ to a map $g_1$ with $g_1 \vert_A=1$

Let $h_t:X \to X$ be a homotopy from $gf=h_0$ to $1=h_1$. Since  $f\vert_A=1$ we can view $h_t \vert_A$ as a homotopy from $g\vert _A$ to $1$.Since $(Y,A)$ has HEP, we can extend this homotopy to a homotopy $g_t: Y \to X$ from $g=g_0$ to a map $g_1$ with $g_1 \vert_A=1$

**Step2:** Show $g_1f$ is homotopic to $1$ rel $A$.

It is easy to obtain the homotopy between $g_1f$ and $1$ by using the homotopies of step $1$ and using transitivity. But the hard work is to construct a homotopy which is rel $A$. The proof is given in Hatchers book on page $17$ chapter $0$ but i dont follow the proof. Basically i don't see the motivation of that proof. Can anyone give me 'rough' idea to find a relative homotopy between $g_f$ and $1$

**Thank you for all your time**

Comment: I may write more later but as a suggestion you should look at the case $A$ is a singleton, to see what is going on. The result then says that if $x$  is well pointed in $X$ and $f(x)$ is well pointed in $Y$, the homotopy equivalence $f: X \to Y$ is also a based homotopy equivalence. A more general result than May's is in Chapter 7 of my book "Topology and Groupoids" (as it was in the 1968 edition, "Elemenets of Modern Topology"). but I don't have time now to write a detailed comparison and answer.

Comment: Prof. @RonnieBrown thank you,it will really be helpful if you will find some time to write a answer of this question.Regards,